# Nginx load banlance: why ip in upstream is always inner ip?

Tags: nginx

I saw many tutorial using inner ip to define upstream:

```
upstream MyUpstream {
server 10.0.0.201 weight=3;
server 10.0.0.202 weight=2;
server 10.0.0.203;
}
```

As you can see, 10.*.*.* is inner ip. I don't understand. Isn't it should be some outer ip for some server?

I mean, if the servers in upstream block are inner ip, it means that they are all in a single real server, then it's meaningless to set such a load banlance.

Comment: What, on earth, is an inner IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're referring to using "inner ip", but if you're asking why these are IPs for "private internets" as defined in RFC 1918:

I guess in many tutorials `nginx` is facing the evil public internet, while the `backends` / `upstreams` aren't and shouldn't (for example due to security reasons) being exposed directly.

Using your example: 10.0.0.0/8 isn't routed publicly, so it's not possible to hit the `backends` / `upstreams` directly; all requests flow trough `nginx`.

> I mean, if the servers in upstream block are inner ip, it means that they are all in a single real server, then it's meaningless to set such a load banlance.

I doubt that this is meaningless, and at least your assumption of "it means that they are all in a single real server" is wrong. What makes you think so?

Comment: yeah, private IPs. If I have three real servers whose outer IPs is X, Y, Z. how does nginx dispatch requests to X Y Z?

Comment: @xiang Not really sure what you're talking about. `nginx` sends the requests via a (private) network. Imagine four machines: [m]achine 1 hosts `nginx` and got two network interfaces: One connecting to the public internet, one connecting to a private network, not exposed to the public internet. The other three machines m1/m2/m3 are hosting the `backend` / `upstream` and only got interfaces connected to this private network. Does this make sense you?